# Encoding categorical features to use in KMeans clustering

Tags: python, k-means, categorical-data

I have a dataset containing both numerical and categorical features(non-numerical) while categorical features can have many values(unlimited).
I need to convert this data to form a KMeans clustering model.

Currently, I have encoded all non-numerical data to numerical format in the training process using a python function and I use the same function to encode non-numerical data during the testing process. Below code is the function I used to encode non-numerical features.

```
def handle_non_nemeric(df):
  columns = df.columns.values

  for column in columns:
    text_digit_dict = {}
    def convert_to_int(val):
      return text_digit_dict[val]

    if(df[column].dtype != np.float64 or df[column].dtype != np.int64):
      column_content = df[column].values.tolist()
      unique_elements = set(column_content)
      x = 1

      for unique in unique_elements:
        if unique not in text_digit_dict:
          if unique == 0 or unique == '-':
            text_digit_dict[unique] = 0

          else:
            text_digit_dict[unique] = x
            x += 1

      df[column] = list(map(convert_to_int, df[column]))
```

When I apply this function to encode non-numerical features during the testing process, a numerical value can be assigned to non-numerical data while it has another numerical value in the training phase. Will it be a problem for my testing process?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great article about encoding categorical features in train and test sets:

https://medium.com/@vaibhavshukla182/how-to-solve-mismatch-in-train-and-test-set-after-categorical-encoding-8320ed03552f

It also explains how to make equal categorical codes in train and test. And they should be equal if you want your model to predict with good precision.